# XCode 6 infinite building

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have really strange problem. I'm writing swift ios project. It has some swift files. One of them is internet requester, which contains some small methods (5-6 rows). If i write 8 methods, my project builds in a second and runs well. But if i add extra method (it can be empty), builder stucks at "compiling swift files" for an inifinite time, PC starts lagging hardly and sometimes "source kit service" terminates. Can you help me?

Comment: When you say PC do you mean Mac?

Comment: Do you use cyrillic in logs? I had similar problem when tried to copy/paste Japanese. And what xCode 6 Beta do you use?

Comment: @MaximShoustin i use only english letter. Xcode beta 4

Comment: Perhaps try with Beta 6

Comment: Just making sure you did mean Mac that's all. But I would upgrade to beta 6 like `Paulw11` has said could be an issue with that version.